# When to participate to an event when payoff is divided between all participants?

Tags: game-theory

There are $n$ people who can participate in some event in exchange of some participation cost $x$. If $m$ people participate in the event, then the payoff for each participant is $\frac{1}{m}$. This is repeated $k$ times, and everyone has access to the number of participants history for all the past events.

What's the best strategy to determine when to participate in the event?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on a couple of things. Is a person allowed to participate more than once? Does each person have to participate eventually?

Comment: Everyone can participate as many times as they want, and they don't have to participate. Based on the participation history, they have to make a choice whether to participate in the next event (they participate when they think there will be less than $\lceil \frac{1}{x} \rceil$ participants).

Comment: What is the source of the problem? Is it from a book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more specification about how choices are made, there's not enough information to determine an optimal strategy.

Here's one possible interpretation . . .

Let $n,x$ be fixed and known, where $n$ is an integer with $n\ge 2$, and $x$ is a real number with $0 < x < 1$.

Suppose the players agree in advance on a probability $p\in [0,1]$ (and are contractually obligated to abide by their agreement) such that each player will independently choose to play with probability $p$.

The question is then: What is the optimal value of $p$, given $n$ and $x$?

With this interpretation, history is irrelevant.

Thus, it suffices to determine the optimal value of $p$ for a single game.

By optimal, assume the goal is to maximize expected value.

For a single game, if $e$ is a player's expected value with all players using the mixed strategy $p$, then
$$
e=\sum_{m=1}^n {\small{\binom{n-1}{m-1}}}p^{m}(1-p)^{n-m}\left({\small{\frac{1}{m}}}-x\right)
$$
which is maximized when
$$p=1-x^{\bigl({\Large{\frac{1}{n-1}}}\bigr)}$$
yielding the expected value
$$
\frac{1}{n}-x+\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)x^{\left({\Large{\frac{n}{n-1}}}\right)}
$$